# Unable to add 2dSphere index to array of locations

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add an 2dSphere index to a Mongo Collection that contains an array of locations. This is the error I'm getting:

```
[MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:
   { _id: "gjuFiwHd7ctBpgEwL",
     title: "Iny orple taoland.",
     locations: [
         { loc: 
             { type: "Point", coordinates: [ "0.0181033", "43.8355792" ] }
         }
     ]
   }
]
```

Where I'm calling:

```
ensureIndex({ 'locations.loc': "2dsphere" })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2dsphere, points are specified in [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format. A point is give by a two-element array, representing`[longitude,latitude]`. You should change your `coordinates` array.

The `lon` and `lat` points shouldn't be wrapped in double qoutes.

It should be:

`{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ 0.0181033, 43.8355792] }`

Comment: D'oh! I was seeding the database using random data and I'd used toFixed() to restrict the float. I didn't realise that it returned a string!

Comment: @tarmes it happens to the best of us.

Comment: @AbdullahRasheed I am getting error "unable to find index for $geoNear query" when my array contains more than 1 locations.